# Rsyslog v8 imfile directory wildcard

Tags: logging, centos, rsyslog

I am trying to solve "sending" log files from directories and subdirectories to central log server using imfile in Rsyslog.

OS is CentOS 7

```
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

Rsyslog is v8 from official repo.

```
rsyslogd 8.26.0, compiled with:
    PLATFORM:                               x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
    PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):
    FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
    GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              No
    FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
    32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
    64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
    memory allocator:                       system default
    Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
    uuid support:                           Yes
    Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 6
```

This Rsyslog version support wildcards on directory level. But it looks like it is not support directory wildcards with imfile.

https://www.slideshare.net/rainergerhards1/using-wildcards-with-rsyslogs-file-monitor-imfile/4

Problem is there is lot of directories in my case (and new are dynamically created) so I cannot create config for each directory.

I noticed that Rsyslog send all new files from all directories (including all wildcards subdirectories) to central log server when is restarted. But when new file is created after restart Rsyslog did not start "send" this file to central log server.

Workaround could by restart Rsyslog each X minutes, but I don't think it is good idea.

Can you please help me find some workaround or another configuration to handle this problem (maybe newer version of Rsyslog support it)?

Best regards,
cr4wen

Answer (score 0):

From what I know about rsyslog, this version should support wildcards in filenames and folders, but I know there was a bug where it didn't pick up newly created files. Maybe an update to the latest version avaialble for CentOS 7 would help.

But the most important thing to ensure is that you are using imfile in inotify mode, wildcards don't work well without that mode enabled.